# How to LogIn as root in Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Tags: server, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, vps

I don't know why Internet giant Google has no instant chat support or ticketing support system for their services.

I have created a new instance under Google cloud compute engine with linux centos-6. Now i want to log into system via SSH with full root access so that i can install other softwares.

When i simply connect SSH through browser windows I see something like this "[abc_user@instance-1 ~]$". But this user has no full root access. My question is how to get full root access to my system or how to log in as root e.g. "[root@myserver ~]#" ?

Can you guys help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GCE images I've been using so far had sudo set up.

You can prefix your commands with sudo to act as root, e.g. `sudo rpm ...` or you just hop into a root shell with `sudo -s`

Comment: Every time I forget to add sudo and get a warning, I want to blast the keyboard.

Comment: use `sudo !!` to run last command with sudo and please spare your keyboard